# How can I resize these partitions?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I have two partitions on my 2015 MacBook Air, one running El Capitan 10.11.6 and one running Catalina 10.15.7.

How can I resize these partitions? There are no resize controls in the disk utility partition screen.

[image: diskutil]

```
jaymon@MacBook-Air ~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage El Capitan              218.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         31.7 GB    disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +31.7 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s4
   1:                APFS Volume Catalina - Data         9.7 GB     disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 83.2 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Catalina                11.1 GB    disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS El Capitan             +217.9 GB   disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 47C3B984-58EF-44BA-8097-70CDE83F8248
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! This site works better if you ask, well, only one question per question :-)

Comment: Backup, then erase and add new partitions of the sizes you want. restore data.

Comment: I would have thought for sure there is a way to resize without having to erase... are you sure there is no other way?

Comment: All I gave you is what I would do. You can do something else as you wish. Have a look on here for the issues people have had and those that have lost data...

Comment: This is one of those things that could be done with some very clever juggling in Terminal [way beyond my expertise] or using [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) I wouldn't attempt either without a known-good backup of everything first.